# Using a custom hook in an event handler function?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am a beginner to using React Hooks (i've been using React for a while now though),
and I am trying to use a custom hook in my event handler.

However, I get this error saying

```
React Hook "useMyCustomHook" is called in function "onSubmit" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
```

Here is my code:

```
import MyCustomHook from './myCustomHook';


const MyComponent= () => {
  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const someData = {
      // data
    };
    useMyCustomHook(someData);
  };

  return (
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <div className="form-control">
          // some form content
        </div>
      </form>
  )
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Read https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Comment: About [rules-of-hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#rules-of-hooks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [rules-of-hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) it says:

> Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions. Instead, you can:
>
> - ✅ Call Hooks from React function components.
> - ✅ Call Hooks from custom Hooks (we’ll learn about them on the next page).

That's what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

React built-in hooks or custom hooks should not be used inside a callback. That is one of the rules of hooks. Please read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#rules-of-hooks).